# How to loop through an array enclosed in an Object returned from express.js in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I want to loop through an array enclosed in an object.
How can I do that?

here is the file that produces the object (routes/messages.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Message = require('../models/message');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Message.find()
        .exec(function(err, messages) {
            if (err)
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Success',
                obj: messages
            });
        });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const message = new Message({
        content: req.body.content
    });
    //console.log(req);
    message.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved message',
            obj: result
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is the file that consumes it (message.service.ts) :

```
import {Message} from "./message.model";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

    private messages: Message[] = [];

    //constructor
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    public addMessage(message: Message): Observable<Message>
    {
        this.messages.push(message);
        //const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        //const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        //console.log(this.messages);
        //console.log(message);
        return this.httpClient.post<Message>('http://localhost:3000/message', message);
    }

    //getters
    public getMessages(): Observable<Message[]>
    {
        return this.httpClient.get<Message[]>('http://localhost:3000/message')
            .map( (data: any[]) => {
                //console.log(messages);
                let transformedMessages: Message[] = [];
                for (let message of data.obj) {
                    console.log("inside the loop");
                    transformedMessages.push(new Message(message.content, 'Dummy', message.id, null));
                }
                console.log(transformedMessages);
                this.messages = transformedMessages;
                return transformedMessages;
        });
    }

    public deleteMessage(message: Message): void
    {
        this.messages.splice(this.messages.indexOf(message), 1);
    }
}
```

The last file produces the following error :

> Error:(33, 42) TS2339: Property 'obj' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

The complete project link is here :

```
https://github.com/skiabox/seed-project
```

Comment: `data` is an array. `[].obj` is not a correct syntax.

Comment: You should probably change to : ` for (let message of data) { console.log(message);
                } `

Comment: Thank you I just removed the [] from 'data: any[]' and my code works now!